# Тире или двоеточие на месте пропуска?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, однородные-члены, двоеточие

> У России есть только два надёжных союзника() армия и флот.

Как объяснить постановку тире на месте пропуска? Или здесь может стоять только двоеточие?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможны оба знака препинания.

> Александр III: «У России есть только два союзника: её армия и флот». ([Источник](https://profiok.com/news/detail.php?ID=2419))
>
> – Во всем свете у нас только два верных союзника – наша армия и флот.
> ([Источник](https://citaty.su/u-rossii-tolko-dva-soyuznika-armiya-i-flot))

[**Двоеточие — тире**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189) (Розенталь)

> Самые многочисленные случаи **вариативности знаков препинания** — параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире.
>
> 1. После обобщающего слова **перед перечислением однородных членов предложения** часто ставится **тире** (вместо обычного двоеточия): *Там всё иное — язык, уклад жизни, круг людей* (Коч.); *Всё в них выражало неприязнь — их крикливость, самоуверенность, бесцеремонность* (Гран.)
>
> В заключение можно указать, что в «конкурентной борьбе» двоеточия с тире «победителем» нередко выходит тире. Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что «в целом **тире** — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия» и что «выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире».

Answer (score 3):

Выбор конкретного знака в предложении с обобщающим словом зависит **от расстановки логических ударений.**

Рассмотрим **два варианта**:

(а) ***У России есть только двА надёжных союзника: армия и флот*** (раскрытие содержания).

(б) ***У России есть только два надёжных соЮзника – армия и флот*** (поясняющий комментарий).

Вариант (а)  более предпочтителен, логически выделено количественное числительное с частицей ***только***.

При постановке двоеточия (а не тире) обобщающее слово  приобретает бОльшую значимость, а это важно для этого высказывания.

Answer (score 2):

Голосовала за ответ Александра.

Дополнить хочется следующее. ***Армия и флот*** – это определения-***приложения*** при цельном сочетании сущ.+числ. ***Два союзника (какие именно?) – армия и флот***. Перед приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, ставим тире.

Ср.: ***Два надёжных союзника, армия и флот, есть у России. – Два надёжных союзника – армия и флот – есть у России.***