# Как различить две темы: обобщающие слова перед однородным рядом или обособленный ряд приложений?

Tags: однородные-члены, терминология, приложение

Тема соотносится со следующим вопросом

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461147/Тире-или-двоеточие-на-месте-пропуска](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461147/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)

***У России есть только два союзника: её армия и флот.***

Как рассматривать это предложение?

1. Это обобщающее слово перед однородным рядом. Тогда можно ставить двоеточие или тире.
2. Это определяемое слово (словосочетание) перед однородным рядом приложений. По правилам обособляется тире.

А может ли вообще такой ряд считаться обособленным приложением? Он отвечает на вопрос ***какой***? Этот ряд раскрывает содержание, а не определяет, разве это функция приложения?

Как различить эти темы?

Примечание: вопрос переформулирован.

Comment: Я так и не понял. Что именно вас интересует: может ли обобщающее слово быть приложением по отношению к однородному ряду или наоборот? Ведь изначально, как я понял, вопрос звучал именно так.

Comment: Серж, изначально вопрос был не очень удачно сформулирован, а проблема такая.Одна и та же конструкция может определяться как однородный ряд, отнесенный к обобщающему слову, или как обособленный ряд приложений, отнесенный к определяемому слову. Знаки препинания разные: тире и двоеточие или только тире. Как правильно определить конструкцию и выбрать знаки? Пример дан. Отвечающие определили его по-разному и знаки выбрали разные. Кто прав и почему? Двоеточие можно поставить или нет? В конечном итоге терминология должна быть точной, а  пунктуация должна быть верной. А здесь одни вопросы.

Comment: Я не знаю, обсуждалась ли когда-нибудь эта тема, правомерен ли такой вопрос вообще, но я вижу, что он важен. С моей точки зрения, обобщающее слово определяется по семантическим признакам, а приложения - по  признакам грамматическим. Это более строгое понятие, оно не всегда применимо. В том же вопросе второй отвечающий поправляет первого в части терминологии и постановки знаков, то есть дает совершенно другой ответ, но при этом голосует за первого. Ну вот как это понимать?

Comment: Да, согласен. Но поскольку обобшающее слово выполняет ту же роль, что и однородные члены, то, кажется, проблем не должно быть при разграничении.

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже много раз задумывалась над этим вопросом. Почему в похожих конструкциях иногда хочется поставить тире и считать однородные члены приложениями, а иногда - двоеточие, как при обобщающем слове. Для себя сделала вывод, что с помощью интонации я показываю, что важнее, какую информацию я выделяю как более значимую. Если ряд однородных членов - то поставлю двоеточие. *Рыбак-подледник бывает разный: рыбак-пенсионер, рыбак – рабочий и служащий, рыбак-военный, рыбак-министр, так сказать, государственный деятель, рыбак-интеллигент.* Если же однородные члены скорее считаю дополнительной информацией, второстепенной, то поставлю тире. *Летом на озерах и болотах появляется огромное количество насекомых - комаров и мошек.*

Comment: Я позже разбирала для себя эту тему (можете посмотреть в моем конспекте https://proza.ru/2020/11/05/1007 ).  Я пришла к такому выводу. Выделять приложения среди других однородных членов не нужно, так как ряд приложений – ЭТО ЧАСТНЫЙ СЛУЧАЙ ОБЫЧНОГО РЯДА. Приложения образуют ряды в двух случаях: (1) ряд имен собственных после нарицательного имени; (2) ряд видовых названий после родового названия.

Comment: Оба эти случая регулируются правилами для обобщающих слов, то есть специальных правил для приложений НЕ ТРЕБУЕТСЯ.  Если ряд состоит из двух членов, связанных союзом И, то это вообще особый случай, там свои правила.  А для предложения с обобщающим словом вы понимаете тему верно: с помощью тире мы обозначаем присоединительный характер ряда, в то время как при двоеточии ряд является более значимым. Интонационно варианты тоже хорошо различаются.

Answer (score 1):

В справочнике Розенталя говорится следующее.

Если однородные члены предложения носят характер **приложения** или уточнения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия **может** ставиться тире: **Алый свет нежно заливал окрестности — ветряную мельницу, шиферные крыши машинно-тракторной станции, элеваторы (Кат.); Легенды и сказки любят все — дети и взрослые; Положительные черты характера проявляются всё равно в чём — в сдержанности, в терпеливости, в смелости; Друг мой был человек замечательный — умный, добрый, чуткий, готовый в любую минуту прийти на помощь.**

В разделе же [Вариативные знаки препинания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189) приведены пример, где возможно употребления двоеточия и тире.
М**ы оба художники (: —) и ты и я. [См. также § 15, п. 5 и 9.](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_15.htm#ppp_5)**

То есть, как мы видим, в подобных примерах,где однородный ряд является приложением,  возможен выбор между тире и двоеточием.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, обобщающим словом называют общее определение **для однородных членов**. Так, в вашем примере "Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов" - однородные члены. Как вы понимаете, далеко не в каждом предложении есть однородные члены. Например:

> Писатель-классик рисовал картины из жизни крестьян.

Здесь "классик" - приложение, но никаких обобщающих слов нет, так как обобщать нечего. Верно и обратное:

> Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов - все они рисовали картины из жизни крестьян.

Здесь есть обобщающее слово (сочетание), но приложения нет.

Поэтому неверно звучит формулировка "как определяется... обобщающее слово применительно к нарицательному существительному": обобщающее слово определяется по отношению к однородным членам, и через отношение к нарицательному существительному его определить нельзя. Соответственно "видом приложения" оно тоже не является.

Вероятно, вы хотели спросить что-то другое. Возможно, почему Розенталь не считает данный пример обобщением? Наверное, нужно переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос переформулирован.

Comment: Экспресс-ответ. Это не может быть второй случай, так как приложение - это существительное, имеющее ту же грамматическую форму падежа и числа, что и определяемое слово. Здесь число другое.

Comment: Словосочетание (неразложимое) в И.п.